# Can jump a kinematic body from a rigidbody in godot?

Tags: godot, rigid-bodies

I found this code to push a rigidbody with a kinematic body in godot:

```
for index in get_slide_count():
        var collision = get_slide_collision(index)
        if collision.collider.is_in_group("bodies"):
            collision.collider.apply_central_impulse(-collision.normal * push)
```

This code works but when the player stand on rigidbody can't jump!!
P.S. I have set the  infinite_inertia to false. All code is this:

```
extends KinematicBody2D


onready var animation = $AnimationPlayer
export (int, 0, 200) var push = 30
var velocity :=Vector2.ZERO
var gravity := 30
var speed := 50
var jumpforce = 300

func _physics_process(delta) -> void:
    #Push()
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        $Sprite.flip_h=false
        velocity.x += speed
        animation.play("Walk")
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        $Sprite.flip_h=true
        velocity.x -= speed
        animation.play("Walk")
    else:
        animation.play("Idle")
    
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y =- jumpforce
        animation.play("Idle")
    velocity.y += gravity
    Push()

    
    velocity=move_and_slide(velocity,Vector2.UP, false, 4, PI/4, false)
    velocity.x= lerp(velocity.x,0,0.2)


func Push():
    for index in get_slide_count():
        var collision = get_slide_collision(index)
        if collision.collider.is_in_group("bodies"):
            collision.collider.apply_central_impulse(-collision.normal * push)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem!!! I set the rigitbody 's mass property from editor to 2 instead 1 . Is working now :)